# Disable most recent & view all (TABS) on nav-menu.php

Tags: posts, menus, pages, navigation

I'm looking for a way to disable Most recent & View all (TABS) on nav-menu.php (in red on the picture).

I want to have only the search bar for my pages and posts.

Thanks.
[image]

UPDATE  :

that what i have now :

[image]

and that what i want to have :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a js file exclusively for admin panel doing this in functions.php:

```
//Admin JS
add_action('admin_init', 'custom_admin_js');
function custom_admin_js() {
    wp_register_script( 'admin-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/admin.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'admin-js' );
}
```

And in admin.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('*[data-type="tabs-panel-posttype-page-most-recent"]').fadeOut();
    $('*[data-type="page-all"]').fadeOut();
    $('*[data-type="tabs-panel-posttype-page-search"]').trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: I must put admin.js on  JS folder at my root installation?

Comment: No in the theme that you are using in theme folder make another folder called "js" if it doesn't exist and in there make another file called admin.js.

Comment: thanks. I put the js folder with admin.js inside on my child theme and insert the code (first part) on functions.php but  it does not work. can you test the code on your machine please?

Comment: See changes above i made an edit.

Comment: Path like this your-theme/js/admin.js

Comment: it's all most good. the 2 tabs are hidden but i'm still on tab 1(most recent) and i want to be on tab 3 (search) by default. (You Can see the UPDATE)

Comment: Check the updated admin.js above